# timeseries object frequency

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

Hi I'm new to timeseries so excuse I'm asking trivial questions, I have two questions:

1. I have hourly dataset (`solar radiation`) 7am - 7pm (12 hours for each day) what can I choose frequency for ts object? 
   I did this `xts_2014.ts  <- ts(xts_2014, frequency=12)` but I think it recognize my data as monthly I know it's wrong but I don't know if 24 works when I don't have full 24 hours just daylight hours.
2. I have the raw data in black (which exhibits seasonal daily pattern and as far as I can tell yearly pattern), I tried moving average for removing noise of order 13 (hours) I don't know if I can proceed in trying to make data stationary?

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC8EZ.png)

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Per `ts` : frequency - the number of observations per unit of time. This does not appear to be the case for your question you have 1 observation per unit of time. Try with a frequency of 1?